# Rails 5 / Simple form - filter association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

In my form I have an association where I want to possible choices to be reduced to those records of the associated object that are active. As per read me of Simple form I use:

```
<%= f.association :documenttype, collection: Documenttype.active.order(:name) %>
```

returns

> undefined method 'active' ...

what am i doing wrong

Comment: How are we supposed to know? You are not providing any useful information - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: On my 'Documenttype' model I have a field 'active' and understood that 'Documenttype.active.order(:name)' is how to get it. Like 'Documenttype.all.order(:name)' gives me all document types. Clearly I misunderstand; what information should I give more please?

Comment: Start with the model and the schema if your are using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a scope on your model.

```
class Documenttype < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
```

This assumes that you have a boolean column in your table named `active`.  If you determine it some other way, you'd modify the `scope` as per your needs, for example, perhaps you have a `status` string column which must have the string "approved", so you'd have...

```
class Documenttype < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> { where(status: 'approved') }
```